# When is /etc/crontab checked?

Tags: cron, anacron

I read on cron man page:

> Cron searches `/var/spool/cron` for crontab files which are named after accounts in `/etc/passwd`; The found crontabs  are  loaded  into  the  memory.   Cron  also  searches  for
>          `/etc/anacrontab`  and  any files in the `/etc/cron.d` directory, which have a different format (see `crontab(5)`).  Cron examines all stored crontabs and checks each job to see if
>          it needs to be run in the current minute

And then it says:

> `/etc/crontab` system crontab.  Nowadays the file is empty by default.  Originally it was usually used to run daily, weekly, monthly jobs.  By default these jobs are now run  through anacron which reads `/etc/anacrontab` configuration file.  See `anacrontab(5)` for more details.

Ok, is clear for me what happens if `/etc/crontab` is empty.

My question is: if anyway `/etc/crontab` exists, when is it read?

Note: Man page is from CentOS 8.

Comment: The original UNIX cron implementation does not read `/etc/crontab` at all anymore...

Comment: Could you cite the source?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/cmd/cron/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the exact variant of `cron` you’re interested in.

In Debian, the `cron` daemon is [documented as reloading `/etc/crontab` whenever necessary](https://manpages.debian.org/cron/cron.8#NOTES):

> Like `/etc/crontab`, the files in the `/etc/cron.d` directory are monitored for changes.

and indeed, [the main loop reloads all the `cron` databases at every iteration](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/blob/52bacc70b592d354efff8231375bf2d51bd4ef52/cron.c#L175) (the loads only happen if files have changed).

In Fedora, and derivatives (including CentOS), `cron` [behaves similarly](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/master/src/cron.c#L371), with additional help from `inotify` if available.

Comment: But Debian is not `UNIX` (e.g. because it uses the non-compliant `dash` as `/bin/sh`) and `UNIX` specifies the only valid interface to `cron` via the command `crontab`.

Comment: Since Linux claims to be a UNIX alike, this reply looks a bit strange. The official documentation is obvious: you must not rely on a specific path used for crontab files, see my answer.

Comment: If you depend on a vendor specific deviation, you need to be prepared to fail at any time when the vendor decides to change the behavior. This is in special true for your answer since you did not describe the behavior documented for the installation related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `cron` implementation that documents a `crontab` file at all, you must be on a historic `UNIX` variant. Since more than 30 years, the only valid interface to the `cron` utility is via the `crontab` command.

This is the reason, why `POSIX` does not document the `cron` utility at all, as it is an implementation specific detail.

So be sure to behave correct and only use `crontab -l` to list crontabs or `crontab -e` to edit crontabs.

If you edit your crontab, the `crontab` command then stores the crontab file on a system specific location and informs the `cron` utility that a crontab has been changed and needs to be reread.